# AutoScrolling Slow down

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I found this, but got no idea how to slow it down:

```
var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
myTextLoader.addEventListener (Event.COMPLETE,onLoaded); 
function onLoaded (e:Event):void 
{ 
    tekstbx.text = e.target.data; 
    tekstbx.addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME,efh); 
} 

myTextLoader.load (new URLRequest("tekst.txt")); 
function efh (event:Event):void 
{ 
    event.currentTarget.scrollV += 1; 
    if (event.currentTarget.scrollV>=event.currentTarget.maxScrollV) 
    { 
        event.currentTarget.scrollV-=1; 
        event.currentTarget.removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME,efh); 
        event.currentTarget.addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME,efV); 
    } 

} 
function efV (event:Event):void 
{ 
    event.currentTarget.scrollV-=1; 
    if (event.currentTarget.scrollV<=1) 
    { 
        event.currentTarget.scrollV-=1; 
        event.currentTarget.removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME,efV); 
        event.currentTarget.addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME,efh); 
    } 

}
```

Comment: You should be a lot more specific. Slow down how? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well it's a scrolling text so far, but all the tekst flashes by verry fast

Answer (score 1):

You could either replace the listener on `ENTER_FRAME` with a `Timer`: you will then slow the scroll by using a larger delay on your timer. 
Or you can change all the "1"s by a smaller number (you should then use a constant to be sure the value is the same everywhere when you change it).

Comment: ok , i'm not home in AS3, so could you give me some code where i can build from or Ready to Use code

Comment: @Joshua: This is not a site to get code written by others. It's a site to get help from others for problems you encounter while writing your *own* code. If you have no experience in AS3, either leave it, learn it, or pay someone to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since `TextField::scrollV` is an `int`, you cannot simply slow it down. You could use @Kodiak's solution to scroll less frequently, which will result in a movement, that is slower, but also less smooth.

Alternatively, you could have a look at [`DisplayObject::scrollRect`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scrollRect). This will allow you scrolling on based on pixels, rather than text lines.